# Command Line Arguments and File Input

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, command-line, command-line-arguments

I had a terrible time with file input from command line arguments last semester and I need to utilize it for an exercise that I am working on. I have coded a simple shell just to get it working:

**prob_5.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
int i;
FILE *fp;
int c;

for (i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
    fp = fopen(argv[i], "r");

    if (fp == NULL) {
        fprint(stderr, "cat: can't open %s\n", argv[i]);
        continue;
    }

    while ((c = getc(fp)) != EOF) {
        putchar(c);
    }

    fclose(fp);
}

return 0;
}
```

I can't seem to remember what the commands are for invoking my program from the command line. I have tried:

```
gcc -o prob_5 -g -ansi prob_5.c
```

I have reformatted my computer since last semester, so perhaps I am missing a System Path?

Comment: What error are you getting? What is the question exactly anyway?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your program just expects one argument: the file name. You also have to compile it first.

```
$ gcc -o prob_5 prob_5.c
$ ./prob_5 input_file.txt
```

If it is not compiling, then you have another issue. What is returned when you execute `gcc`?

Comment: Thanks. I can't remember if I was able to compile via command line on my Windows 7 system or if I used a VCL connection. Does Windows recognize the gcc command? Do I need do add any Paths to System or Environment Variables? I'm using MS Visual Studio 2010 if that helps.

Comment: Well, that changes things a bit. `gcc` is a standard Linux program, it will only work on Windows 7 if you have installed it and it is in the path. If you are using Visual Studio, you should probably compile and run it through the GUI.

Comment: Gotcha. I must have logged into a Linux shell last semester to compile as I don't remember getting it to run with an input file through VS. Right clicking on my prob_5.c file and selecting properties, I am under Command Line and see these options:

/ZI /nologo /W3 /WX- /Od /Oy- /D "WIN32" /D "_DEBUG" /D "_WINDOWS" /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" /Gm /EHsc /RTC1 /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Fp"Debug\prob_5.pch" /Fa"Debug\" /Fo"Debug\" /Fd"Debug\vc100.pdb" /Gd /analyze- /errorReport:queue 

Which would I use to pass my input.txt parameter?

Comment: Those are the compiler arguments. You want the execution arguments. I don't know where that would be in the settings, since I haven't used Visual Studio in a long time. If you still have access to that Linux shell, it is probably looking a little better, eh?

Comment: Logged back into a Linux shell to try to get this working. gcc -o prob_5 prob_5.c returns the following errors: prob_5.c: (.text+0x68): undefined reference to 'fprint' collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Ah, that would be because it is supposed to be `printf`. I'm not sure where you got that from.

Comment: Jeez, it's been a long day. Thanks for the help. I must sound like a clutz.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3506/discussion-between-raphnguyen-and-chriszuma)