# Unix Command Line Parameter Help

Tags: c, unix, command-line, command-line-arguments

I am currently trying to read in an input file of 15,000 integers and pass these values into an array. I'm really rusty when it comes to passing command line arguments into the program, so perhaps I am not doing this the correct way. Here is what I have coded thus far:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
int i;
FILE *fp;
int c;
int values[15000];
char line[32];
int index = 0;

for (i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
    fp = fopen(argv[i], "r");

    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf(stderr, "cat: can't open %s\n", argv[i]);
        continue;
    }

    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp) != NULL) {
        scanf(line, "%d", values[index];
        index++;
    }

    fclose(fp);
}

return 0;
}
```

I am invoking gcc -o prob_5 input.txt from the command line and am receiving this error message:

```
/usr/bin/ld:input.txt: file format not recognized; treating as linker script
/usr/bin/ld:input.txt: syntax error
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Is there an error with my code or the command line arguments, or both?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Command Line Arguments and File Input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7437502/command-line-arguments-and-file-input)

Comment: @sehe Yes, I wasn't sure what the protocol was for asking questions on a continual exercise. I thought that I should edit the post whenever I hit a new problem, but someone suggested that I submit a new question for each stopping point in able to get answers quicker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
gcc -o prob5 prob5.c
./prob5 input.txt
```

Assuming that the source file (shown...) is named prob5.c - you don't mention that :)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i;
    FILE *fp;
    int values[15000];
    char line[32];
    int index = 0;

    for (i = 1; i < argc; i++)
    {
        fp = fopen(argv[i], "r");

        if (fp == NULL)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "cat: can't open %s\n", argv[i]);
            continue;
        }

        while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp) != NULL && (index < 15000))
        {
            sscanf(line, "%d", &values[index]);
            index++;
        }

        fclose(fp);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Whoops! My source file is actually named prob_5.c. And thanks! I just caught the missing parenthesis as well.

Comment: regarding the scanf fix, wel... I fixed the fix too. :)

Comment: Am I reading the values into the array appropriately? I have a printf("%d", values[0]); statement to test that there is a value at the first index but the program does not return anything.

Comment: Because you were doing good, I'll simply post my 'fixed up' version. If anything, it will become of test of how good you master a diff to see what changed - and come up with the why part

Comment: Thanks! Any insight on the Segmentation fault?

Comment: Yep. There is none with my code. Perhaps you missed a difference (wink wink). You _might_ want to add error checking to the sscanf (though that is not the fix for the segfault; it is before that line)

Comment: Yes, I caught the index < 15000 error check and added it to my code. I can't see where else it may be acc.... doh! &value[index] seems to have fixed it.

Comment: Cheers. Next time please mention when the challenge was to find/fix the errors :) make it a lot clearer to us what you're doing and what you're supposed to learn. (For your conscience: did you _understand_ all of the fixes? Hint: you need to really read the manpage for sscanf/scanf on %d and sscanf at least; Also did you the spot the one thing that was harmless but also not useful? I deleted it :)) Good luck

Comment: Yes, I saw that I had an int c in there that didn't actually do anything. You were just so quick to catch the errors! I understand the error check for index < 15000. Even though the assignment will have exactly 15000 or less values, it is always good practice to check for errors in your code. I thought that with arrays I could leave off the &, but I guess I remembered wrong. fprintf() and sscanf() must be Linux specific? I am coding in VS and then compiling through a Linux shell, so sometimes I miss these little differences.

Comment: Ok  for learning: the functions are portable (POSIX, IIRC) so they should behave the same on MSVC. An array 'is' a pointer (_decays into a pointer_) but values[index] is not an array (hint: it is an array element). So, you did remember correctly but the computer beat you at formally interpreting the code just this once  :) - for fun:  values + index == &values[index]. Sleep well, m8

Comment: @raphnguyen: `sscanf` and `fprintf` are not just POSIX. They are actually required in a conformant C standard library by the C standard. Every C implementation must have these functions in order to truthfully call itself standard C.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your execution. `gcc` is a compiler/linker and you shouldn't pass in your input files:

```
gcc -o prob_5 prob_5.c
./prob_5 input.txt
```

Comment: Thanks! I should have mentioned that I have tried this as well and got a bunch of errors. Just noticed my missing parenthesis on line 20.

Answer (score 1):

You need to compile the source code

```
gcc prob_5.c -o prob_5
```

and then run the binary with command-line parameters

```
./prob_5 input.txt
```

What happens with what you're doing is the compiler trying to interpret a bunch of numbers as source code.